# Fleet Telematics Custom Routes

Tags: here-api

I would like to apply a road restriction using Fleet Telematics API. But everytime I try to use example from the docs, I am getting 400 response. Is this because I am sending parameters incorrectly or it works only for paid plans? I am currently freemium.

HERE example says that `overlay_spec` needs to be send as a JSON string parameter. Probably that's my issue. Can anyone help me construct proper curl command?

Here is what I am using now:

```
curl -X GET \
  'http://cre.api.here.com/2/overlays/upload.json?app_id=MY_APP_ID&app_code=MY_APP_CODE&map_name=OVERLAYNA&overlay_spec=%5B%0A%20%20%7B%20%22op%22%3A%22override%22%2C%0A%20%20%22shape%22%3A%5B%5B50.10765%2C8.68774%5D%2C%5B50.10914%2C8.68771%5D%5D%2C%0A%20%20%22layer%22%3A%22LINK_ATTRIBUTE_FCN%22%2C%0A%20%20%22data%22%3A%7B%22VEHICLE_TYPES%22%3A%220%22%7D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20%22op%22%3A%22create%22%2C%0A%20%20%22shape%22%3A%5B%5B50.10937%2C8.68422%5D%2C%5B50.10807%2C8.68525%5D%2C%5B50.10737%2C8.68387%5D%5D%2C%0A%20%20%22data%22%3A%7B%22NAMES%22%3A%22ENGBNDemo%20Road%22%7D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20%22op%22%3A%22override%22%2C%0A%20%20%22shape%22%3A%5B%5B50.10937%2C8.68422%5D%2C%5B50.10807%2C8.68525%5D%2C%5B50.10737%2C8.68387%5D%5D%2C%0A%20%20%22layer%22%3A%22TRUCK_RESTR_FCN%22%2C%0A%20%20%22data%22%3A%7B%22VEHICLE_TYPES%22%3A%22truck%22%2C%20%22WEIGHT_RESTRICTION%22%3A%223300%22%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%5D'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please retry your request. Looks like a temporary outage. We tried and was able to get the below response for your above request.

Request:

```
http://cre.api.here.com/2/overlays/upload.json?map_name=OVERLAYNA&overlay_spec=%5B%7B%22op%22:%22override%22,%22shape%22:%5B%5B50.10765,8.68774%5D,%5B50.10914,8.68771%5D%5D,%22layer%22:%22LINK_ATTRIBUTE_FCN%22,%22data%22:%7B%22VEHICLE_TYPES%22:%220%22%7D%7D%5D&storage=readonly
```

Response:

```
{
    "layers": [
        "LINK_FC3",
        "LINK_ATTRIBUTE_FC3",
        "TRUCK_RESTR_FC3",
        "ROAD_ADMIN_FC3",
        "ROAD_GEOM_FC3"
    ],
    "meta": [
        {
            "layerId": "LINK_FC3",
            "lastUpdateTimeStamp": 1542030162597
        },
        {
            "layerId": "LINK_ATTRIBUTE_FC3",
            "lastUpdateTimeStamp": 1542030162624
        },
        {
            "layerId": "TRUCK_RESTR_FC3",
            "lastUpdateTimeStamp": 1542030162711
        },
        {
            "layerId": "ROAD_ADMIN_FC3",
            "lastUpdateTimeStamp": 1542030162843
        },
        {
            "layerId": "ROAD_GEOM_FC3",
            "lastUpdateTimeStamp": 1542030162964
        }
    ],
    "response_code": "201 Created"
}
```